# Получить всех workers, у которых отсутствует хотя бы одно значение в таблице workers_orders_types

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Есть три таблицы:

1. workers (id, name) - таблица работников
2. orders_types (id, name) - таблица типов заказов. Их 7. По умолчанию, они все соответствуют работникам
3. workers_orders_types (id, worker_id, type_id) - таблица связывает workers и orders_types. НО! В это таблице хранятся типы заказов, от которых работник отказался.

Нужно вывести всех workers, у которых отсутствует хотя бы один из типов заказов в таблице workers_orders_types. Например, мы запрашиваем работников, которые не отказались от типов заказов с id 1 или 2 или 3. Допустим, работник отказался от типов заказов с id 2 и 3 то он должен попасть  в выборку т.к. от 1 он не отказался.
У меня пока получилось что то типа:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `workers` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM`orders_types`
    INNER JOIN `workers_orders_types` ON `orders_types`.`id` = `workers_orders_types`.`type_id` 
    WHERE`workers`.`id` = `workers_orders_types`.`worker_id` 
    AND `type_id` IN (1, 2, 3)
);
```

Но этот запрос уже не выводит работника если он отказался хотя бы 1 из параметров 1,2,3  т.к. NOT EXISTS будет true, если в подзапросе есть хотя бы 1 строка

Возможно ли составить правильный запрос по принципу И 1 И 2 И 3 сразу?

UPD
В комментариях предложили вариант с сравнением суммы type_id. Написал такой запрос:

```
SELECT workers.id, SUM(workers_eorders_types.type_id) AS total_type_id 
FROM workers 
LEFT JOIN workers_orders_types ON workers.id = 
workers_orders_types.worker_id 
GROUP BY workers.id 
HAVING total_type_id = 1 + 2 + 3
```

Но, он будет выдавать одинаковые результаты на 1+2+3 или 1+2+6, 1+3+5 и т.д.

Comment: Если работник ни от чего не отказался, SUM(type_id) для него будет 28. Иначе - меньше. Если надо проверить только набор 1,2,3, то добавить соотв. WHERE и проверять, что сумма (не) равна 6..

Comment: Да, идея норм! сделал так:
SELECT workers.id, SUM(workers_eorders_types.type_id) AS total_type_id
FROM workers
LEFT JOIN workers_orders_types ON workers.id = workers_orders_types.worker_id
GROUP BY workers.id
HAVING total_type_id = 1 + 2 + 3
А уже что прокидывать для сложения буду на стороне приложения!

Comment: Если задано 2+3+4=9, то может быть 1+2+6, 1+3+5 и т.д.

Comment: Блин, точно... придется переделывать

Comment: @ValNik *Если задано 2+3+4=9, то может быть 1+2+6, 1+3+5 и т.д* Ну если читать только половину совета - то да. А если весь совет- то `WHERE type_id IN (2, 3, 4)`, и ничего подобного быть не может, ибо ни 1, ни 6, ни 5 в группировку и суммирование не попадут.

Comment: Согласен. Мой комментарий был скорее к варианту решения с HAVING total_type_id = 1 + 2 + 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал запрос, получилось вот так:

```
SELECT workers.*
FROM workers
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM orders_types
    WHERE orders_types.id IN (1, 2, 3)
    AND orders_types.id NOT IN (
        SELECT workers_orders_types.type_id
        FROM workers_orders_types
        WHERE workers_orders_types.worker_id = workers.id
    )
)  
ORDER BY `workers`.`id` ASC;
```

Отрабатывает как надо! Теперь отсекает работников, только если у них все 3  параметра присутствуют в таблице workers_orders_types! Соответственно, если хоть 1 отсутствует то выводит!

Answer (score 1):

Если присмотреться к совету @Akina, можно сделать так

```
with t as(SELECT worker_id,count(type_id)  cnt FROM `workers_orders_types`
WHERE `type_id` IN (1, 2, 3)
group by worker_id
)
select w.* ,cnt
from workers w
left join t on t.worker_id=w.id
where cnt<>3 or cnt is null
```

На тестовых данных

```
create table workers (id int , name varchar(2)); -- таблица работников
insert into workers values (1,'W1'),(2,'W2'),(3,'W3');
create table orders_types (id int, name varchar(2)); -- таблица типов заказов. Их 7. По умолчанию, они все соответствуют работникам
insert into orders_types values(1,'T1'),(2,'T2'),(3,'T3'),(4,'T4'),(5,'T5'),(6,'T6'),(7,'T7');
create table  workers_orders_types (id int, worker_id int, type_id int);
insert into workers_orders_types values
 (1,1,2),(2,1,3)
,(3,2,1),(4,2,2),(5,2,3)
,(6,3,4)
;
```

Получится ответ (промежуточный)

| id | name | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | W1 | 2 |
| 2 | W2 | 3 |
| 3 | W3 | null |

И окончательный

| id | name | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | W1 | 2 |
| 3 | W3 | null |

Это стрый вариант -выбрать отказавшихся

```
with t as(
SELECT worker_id,count(type_id) FROM `workers_orders_types`
WHERE `type_id` IN (1, 2, 3)
group by worker_id
 -- отказался от всех из списка
--having count(type_id)=3 -- число должно быть равно числу элементов в списке 
)
select * 
from workers w
inner join t on t.worker_id=w.id
```

Comment: Тут выводит всех, у кого присутствует все 3 параметра, а надо чтобы их отсекало!

Comment: Я добавил вариант, который наоброт. Не совсем понятно, который из них нужен)

Comment: да я сам 1000 раз запутался пока думал, то присутствуют то отсутствуют! Такая вот мудрёная БД! Но спасибо за помощь!

Comment: ``workers_orders_types`` - переименовать бы по смыслу)

Comment: На самом деле, там название еще более замороченное, для вопроса упростил! Но я бы переименовал, например, в workers_ordertypes. По крайней мере, соответствует принципу связующих таблиц, который в laravel принят!